# Execution not getting out of constructor

Tags: sqlite

I am following this tutorial http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

so I created

```
public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    //Log.d("LOGI JEM", "MRENDA CONTEXTIT: " + context.toString());
    this.myContext = context;
}
```

and I am trying to execute it from my main class as in the tutorial:

```
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
    //Log.d("LOGI JEM", "MENIHERE MBAS COPY DATABASE MRENDA IF(DBEXISTS): " );
    myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

but eclipse is telling me that "The constructor DatabaseHelper() undefined" and gives me three fixes but none of the is working for me. Thanks for any support offered...

Answer (score 0):

That's because the constructor is undefined for zero arguments.  You defined it to take a context.  Since you aren't giving it one in line 1 of your 2nd block, it's complaining.

Also, why are you reassigning the value of myDbHelper?  Just initialize it once with new DatabaseHelper(context).

Finally, if the class you're in is not Context, then passing "this" to the constructor will be a type mismatch.

Comment: Well, to be very true, I am new to Android, and I was following the tutorial, so I tried to change that code in many ways but none was going out of the constructor. Probably I have to check the "type mismatch" path. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is more of a Java thing than Android.  It looks like the tutorial is wrong to have the new DatabaseHelper() line.  There isn't a constructor defined for that in the DatabaseHelper Class.  I would eliminate that line.